# Allocating an object that only works as pointer of an abstract class

Tags: c++

My code won't run with the object linked_list from my class LinkedList. It spits out:
 "Variable type 'LinkedListstd::__1::string' (aka 'LinkedList<basic_string<char, char_traits, allocator>>') is an abstract class"

It will work if I change the LinkedList object to a pointer, but then the code doesn't run like it should. Someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
        if (argc < 3)
        {
            cerr << "Please provide name of input and output files";
            return 1;
        }
        cout << "Input file: " << argv[1] << endl;
        ifstream in(argv[1]);
        if (!in)
        {
            cerr << "Unable to open " << argv[1] << " for input";
            return 2;
        }
        cout << "Output file: " << argv[2] << endl;
        ofstream out(argv[2]);

LinkedList<string> linked_list; ///WHY DOES IT HAVE TO BE A POINTER TO WORK????

// process input strings
    for (string line; getline(in, line);)
    {
        string item1, item2;
        if (line.size() == 0) continue;
        out << endl << line;
        istringstream iss(line);
        iss >> item1;
        if (item1 == "Insert")
        {
            while (iss >> item2)
            {
                out << endl << item2;
                linked_list->push_front(item2);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Here is my LinkedList.h file:

```
#ifndef INC_235LAB3_LINKEDLIST_H
#define INC_235LAB3_LINKEDLIST_H
#include "LinkedListInterface.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class LinkedList : public LinkedListInterface<T>{

private:
    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node* next;
        Node(const T& d, Node* n) : data(d), next(n) {}
        ~Node() = default;
    };
    Node* head;

public:
    LinkedList() : head(NULL) {}
    ~LinkedList() { clear(); }

    /** Insert Node(value) at beginning of linked list */
    void push_front(const T& value){
        head = new Node(value, head);
        return;
    }

    /** Remove Node at beginning of linked list */
    void pop_front(){
        if (head == NULL){
            cout << "Empty!" << endl; ///WHY DOES IT NEED TO BE COUT??
        }
        else {
            Node* temp = head;
            head = head->next;

            delete temp;
        }
    }

    /** Return reference to value of Node at beginning of linked list */
    T& front(){
        return head->data; ///TODO IS THIS CORRECT
        ///return head;
    }

    /** Return true if linked list size == 0 */
    bool empty(){
        if (head->next == NULL){
            return true;
        }
            return false;
    }

    /** Remove all Nodes with value from linked list */
    void remove(const T& value){
        // Initialize current
        Node *current = head;

        while (head->data == value){
            head = head->next;
        }
        while (current->next != NULL){
            if (current->next->data == value){
                current->next = current->next->next;
            }
            else{
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
        return head;
    }

    /** Remove all Nodes from linked list */
    void clear(){
        // Initialize current
        Node* current = head;

        while (current != NULL){
            next = current->next;
            free(current);
            current = next;
        }
        head = NULL;
    }

    /** Reverse Nodes in linked list */
    void reverse(){
        // Initialize current, previous & next ptrs
        Node* current = head;
        Node *prev = NULL;
        Node *next = NULL;

        while (current != NULL) {
            // Store next
            next = current->next;
            // Reverse current node's pointer
            current->next = prev;
            // Move pointers one position ahead.
            prev = current;
            current = next;
        }
        head = prev;
    }

    /** Return the number of nodes in the linked list */
    size_t size(){
        // Initialize counter and current
        int counter = 0;
        Node* current = head;

        while (current != NULL){
            current = current->next;
            counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }


    /**Friend operator*/
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, LinkedList& ll)
    {
        Node* node_ptr = ll.head;
        while (node_ptr != NULL)
        {
            os << node_ptr->data << (node_ptr->next != NULL ? " ==> " : "");
            node_ptr = node_ptr->next;
        }
        return os;
    }
};
#endif //INC_235LAB3_LINKEDLIST_H
```

Comment: [Edit] the question to include the definition for `LinkedListInterface`.

Comment: You haven't added the class I requested. It contains one or more pure virtual functions (`= 0;`) that are not overridden in the `LinkedList` class.